# Ultrametric inequality

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am having trouble seeing the following consequence of the [ultrametric inequality](http://books.google.com/books?id=mz5YaayFY60C&pg=PA2&dq=non%20archimedean%20every%20triangle%20is%20isosceles&hl=en&ei=qxbATeyAKdCUtwfYmui_BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=non%20archimedean%20every%20triangle%20is%20isosceles&f=false), which is supposed to be immediate.

If $|x+y|\leq \max{\{|x|,|y|\}}$, then, equality holds when $|x|\neq |y|$.

I looked up three books/notes and all of them just say that this is immediate.

Comment: The details are given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space#Formal_definition

Comment: @lhf: Thanks a lot. That was eating me up.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose that $|x|<|y|$ then $|x+y|\le \max\{|x|,|y|\}=|y|$ but in the other 
>   hand we have $|y|=|y+x-x|\le\max\{|x+y|,|-x|\}=\max\{|x+y|,|x|\}$ so we have
>   $|y|\le\max\{|x+y|,|x|\}\Rightarrow |y|\le|x+y|$ as $|x|<|y|$ then follows that
>   $|y|=|x+y|$. When you suppose $|x|>|y|$ by exactly the same reason that 
>   $|x|=|x+y|$ or just $|x+y|=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$ which finishes the solution.